# Using the iOS backspace character

Tags: ios, ios7

When using the backspace symbol in an app, I want to use the same one iOS (7) uses in its keyboards: [image: native iOS backspace icon]

But instead, when using System Font in Xcode, it shows as a different design:

[image: Xcode's System Font backspace character]

Is there another character that represents the one used by iOS, should I switch to a specific other font, is there a System Icon that should be used for this, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite likely that the system keyboard uses an icon, not any specific Unicode character. Just like the shift keys and some other non-character keys.

Comment: thanks, hope they include these elements in the SDK so we could be more consistent about them collectively